# Decrease the use of 'ifs' in Java Application

Tags: java, if-statement

I am studying Java and my teacher has passed an exercise to the class where there are 4 candidates for an election, and the problem is to check which candidate is the winner and whether or not there will be a second round (show the candidates present and the corresponding votes ). The problem is that it can not be done using arrays, which means I have to do it using only 'if's'.
How do you do it the quickest, keeping in mind that it is possible for both 2 and the 4 candidates to go to the second round?

My progress so far:

```
if(voteLula > voteCiro && voteLula > voteCriancinha && voteLula > voteRose){
       winnervotes = votosLula;
       winner = "Lulalelé";
   }else if(voteCiro > voteLula && voteCiro > voteCriancinha && voteCiro > voteRose){
       winnervotes = votosCiro;
       winner = "Cirogrude";
   }else if(voteCriancinha > voteLula && voteCriancinha > voteCiro && voteCriancinha > voteRose){
       winnervotes = votosCriancinha;
       winner = "Criancinha";
   }else if(voteRose > voteLula && voteRose > voteCiro && voteRose > voteCriancinha){
       winnervotes= votosRose;
       winner = "Roseaçaí";
   }
```

I thought about using "> =" within those loops, but would greatly increase the lines of code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the criterion for going to a second round, two candidates with equal votes? Why 2 or 4, but not 3 of them?

Comment: It can be 3 of them, sorry if you get confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a class to store the name and the votes like that :

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int votes;

    public Person(String name, int votes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.votes = votes;
    }

    //add getter and setter
}
```

And now for the max :

```
public static Person max(Person a, Person b, Person c, Person d) {

    Person max = a;

    if (b.getVotes() > max.getVotes())
        max = b;
    if (c.getVotes() > max.getVotes())
        max = c;
    if (d.getVotes() > max.getVotes())
        max = d;

     return max;
}
```

Your code will be much more readable and comprehensible this way.

I let you think now about the second round, it's not harder to check if there is multiple max.

Answer (score 2):

When this code sits in a method then simply *return* within the "then" blocks. By doing so you remove the need to use else all over the place.

If this code does not sit in its own method then create one!

Given your constraint it might not be possible to reduce the number of if statements. But as said - you can simplify the structure.

Comment: "By doing so you remove the need to use else..." I often think it's a good idea to use else even if the previous if returns something, since it makes the control flow more clear. As a plus, the compiler will tell at you if you forget the return.

Comment: The code by the OP would boil down to 4 simple if blocks using early returns. I don't see how the else blocks in his code add anything meaning of value.